# Serializing fieldset using jQuery in IE11 not working

Tags: jquery, serialization

I want to serialize a fieldset. It works fine in Chrome but in IE11 the `$myFieldset.serialize()` returns an empty string.

I prepared a small fiddle to demonstrate the problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/7ayudwok/2/

If you open it in chrome ir works but not in IE11.

Is there a way to solve this? Or any workaround?

Comment: Yes not working. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28479039/jquery-ajax-serialize-not-working-with-select-in-ie?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: That should be a bug in IE11 but as a sidenote `forms` should be serialized otherwise try creating your serialized string or object.

Answer (score 1):

IE11 does not serialise fieldsets. To get around this, you need to select the elements, and serialise them:

`$('fieldset *').serialize();`

It's not pretty, but it gets the job done and it works across Chrome and Firefox as well.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason IE does not play well with field set serialize action. Where as in chrome, Firefox and safari it would work fine without a peep. To support this in IE you need to change the fieldset to form attribute.

```
<fieldset id="asdasd">  -- Will not work in IE
<form id = "asdasd"> -- Works fine
```